# Did Shurpanaka take revenge on Ravana using Sita?

Tags: ramayana, rama, ravana

I have come across some hear say versions like Shurpanaka took revenge on Ravana using Sita, for the killing of her husband Vidyutjihva.. We have the description of killing of shurpanaka husband in Valmiki Ramayana. But such an explanation of Shurpanaka taking revenge on Ravana for killing of her husband doesn't appear in Valmiki Ramayana.  Have you read it in anyother purana?